# WCF call error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time

Tags: wcf

I've written a WCF service hosted on server 1. I can call it successfully from my local pc, but when I try to call the same function from server 2. it shows below error:

> One or more errors occurred. (A connection attempt failed because the
> connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
> established connection failed because connected host has failed to
> respond.

my code is:

```
 var client = new Sepidar_WcfService.SepidarClient();
 Task<Sepidar_WcfService.ISepidarServiceOutput> tStocks = client.GetStocksAsync("1", "1");
```

the stack trace is:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
> at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result() at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask) at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.AuthenticationHelper.SendWithAuthAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Uri authUri, ICredentials credentials, Boolean preAuthenticate, Boolean isProxyAuth, Boolean doRequestAuth, HttpConnectionPool pool, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.DecompressionHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpClientRequestChannel.HttpClientChannelAsyncRequest.SendRequestAsync(Message message, TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification) at Nop.Services.Catalog.UpdateWarehouses.Execute() at Nop.Services.Tasks.Task.ExecuteTask() at Nop.Core.Caching.MemoryCacheManager.PerformActionWithLock(String key, TimeSpan expirationTime, Action action) in C:\Business\Projects\nopCommerce_4.10_Source\Libraries\Nop.Core\Caching\MemoryCacheManager.cs:line 205 at Nop.Services.Tasks.Task.Execute(Boolean throwException, Boolean ensureRunOncePerPeriod) ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result() at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result() at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.AuthenticationHelper.SendWithAuthAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Uri authUri, ICredentials credentials, Boolean preAuthenticate, Boolean isProxyAuth, Boolean doRequestAuth, HttpConnectionPool pool, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.DecompressionHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpClientRequestChannel.HttpClientChannelAsyncRequest.SendRequestAsync(Message message, TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)<---

any help would be appriciated!

Comment: I think the problem lies with your client. Ping your server ip address from your client to confirm whether the ping works.

Comment: Ping is OK.....

Comment: You can try to open the port or close the firewall directly.

Comment: The firewall is closed. I think it's related to proxy...

Comment: You can try to regenerate the proxy class on server 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, The problem is, I try to call the WCF service with http, while service client has https protocol. Thus the issue is related to "same origin policy" concept.